# Google Patents link on main page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I notice there is a "Search patents with Google" link on the right side of the Ask Patents main page. That links to https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts. I've found that https://patents.google.com is generally more reliable way to search patents with Google. Many time when there are figures missing with the first link you can find them with https://patents.google.com. Is it possible to change the address of the link on the main page?

Actually as of today, I'm getting inaccurate results on all Google patent pages so perhaps providing a link to https://www.lens.org/lens/ would be better. After all, it is non-commercial and arguably better than Google.

Nine months in and no one seems to care about this. We've gotten several questions recently asking why they can't see figures or pdfs and the answer is always "don't use www.google.com/patents".

Comment: @robertcartaino I posted this question nearly 9 months ago and the link is still to the broken google patents site. We continuously get questions asking why the images or pdf is missing and this link is likely one of the reasons. Why can't the moderator simply change it to one of the better options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently Google now has fixed this insanity and either Google patents address goes to the same (and better) site.